# How to return array instead of object in laravel query builder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

Here's my query

```
$author = Author::withCount(['penelitian', 'pengabdian'])->get()->sortBy('nama');
```

But I get something like this

```
"data": {
        "66": {
            "id": 20,
            "nidn": null,
            "nama": "Ach Bakhrul Muchtasib",
            "penelitian_count": 1,
            "pengabdian_count": 1
        } 
 }
```

What should I do to get the results like this

```
"data": [
        {
            "id": 20,
            "nidn": null,
            "nama": "Ach Bakhrul Muchtasib",
            "penelitian_count": 1,
            "pengabdian_count": 1
        }
 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should achieve this by simply chaining toArray() at end of query.

E.g,

```
Author::withCount(['penelitian', 'pengabdian'])->sortBy('nama')->get()->toArray();
```